# Gallery app disappeared

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, gallery

I have a Nexus 5
and I've noticed that the Gallery icon disappeared. I can't find it either in the menu or in the apps settings (running or all).
I don't know exactly when it happened, but for sure after the upgrading to 5.0 Lollilop. Now, to open the pics, I have to launch camera and then swipe to the right.
Did it happen to someone else? Does anybody know how to solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google decided to remove the Gallery app, replacing it by the "Photos" app.

[image: Google Photos]

Comment: Oh... I didn't think about checking that app and reading the upgrading notes. Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you haven't disabled it. Go to Settings -> Apps -> All/Disabled and see if you have disabled it.

Comment: I've already searched it in all apps settings, but it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

I have just went to Settings-APPS-ALL-(Check any Apps set under protected Apps ) by selecting preferences.

I have kept Gallery App under protected Apps ..Now its visible on my home screen once i unchecked the Protected Apps